# I need all the values in my xml to be increased by 1 using xslt

Tags: xslt-1.0

In my xml I want all the values to be increased by 1.
So in the xml below I have only 2 times value and I want value 8 to be 9 and value 5 to be 6.
But this should work for all possible values.

This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><equipmentActualProperties>
<equipmentActualProperty>
    <action>U</action>
    <dataType>Text</dataType>
    <equipmentActualPropertyID>CUST_0002</equipmentActualPropertyID>
    <equipmentActualPropertyValueTexts>
        <equipmentActualPropertyValueText>
            <languageID>EN</languageID>
            <value>8</value>
        </equipmentActualPropertyValueText>
    </equipmentActualPropertyValueTexts>
    <equipmentPropertyID>CUST_0002</equipmentPropertyID>
    <equipmentUse>Other</equipmentUse>
    <hierarchyScope>default</hierarchyScope>
    <requiredByRequestedSegmentResponse>Other</requiredByRequestedSegmentResponse>
</equipmentActualProperty>
<equipmentActualProperty>
    <action>U</action>
    <dataType>Text</dataType>
    <equipmentActualPropertyID>CUST_0001</equipmentActualPropertyID>
    <equipmentActualPropertyValueTexts>
        <equipmentActualPropertyValueText>
            <languageID>EN</languageID>
            <value>5</value>
        </equipmentActualPropertyValueText>
    </equipmentActualPropertyValueTexts>
    <equipmentPropertyID>CUST_0001</equipmentPropertyID>
    <equipmentUse>Other</equipmentUse>
    <hierarchyScope>default</hierarchyScope>
    <requiredByRequestedSegmentResponse>Other</requiredByRequestedSegmentResponse>
</equipmentActualProperty>
```

Comment: Can you use Python to read the XML increase the values and save again?

Comment: No I can not use Python.

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck with this trivial assignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the identity template and push programming to do this.  Also, for this to work, your snippet needs to be within a root node.

```
<!-- Identity template. -->
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="value">
   <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select=". + 1"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```